# Orientation Portrait and PortraitUpSideDown Only For One Window

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, orientation, titanium-alloy

I have 10 windows.

The initial window is loginWindow i want to set orientation for Portrait and PortraitUpSideDown.
For remaining windows will have landscape and portrait orientation.

in Tiapp.xml

```
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
```

Which set all orientation for my application which enables portrait,portraitupsidedown,landscapeLeft and landscapeRight.

I need those only portrait and portraitUpSideDown for LoginWindow.
Rest of window do have all the orientation which is portrait,portraitupsidedown,landscapeLeft and landscapeRight.

Can any one suggest me how can i able to get this behaviours for my application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different windows and define for each window which orientation you want to allow.

I mean, you have to create loginWindow like this:

```
var loginWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT],
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true

});
winPortrait.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT];
```

Windows where you want to allow all orientations, have to been created like this:

```
var appWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true,
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
});
appWindow.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Present your loginWindow as a modal view and after that set this methods for desired orientations.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{            
    return NO;
}

 - (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using different orientation modes for a single app in iOS is not recommended. Please read [**Orientation design principles**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Orientation)

> [Apple's Developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1) says: "People expect to use your
> app in different orientations, and it’s best when you can fulfill that
> expectation." In other words, don't look at handling orientation as a
> bother but an opportunity.
>
> Apple further recommends that when choosing to lock or support
> orientation, **you should consider following these principles:**
>
> On iPhone/iPod Touch – **Don't mix orientation of windows within a single app; so, either lock orientation for the whole app, or react to orientation changes.**
>
> On iPhone – don't support the portrait-upside-down orientation because that could leave the user with their phone upside-down when receiving a phone call.

However you can achieve orientation for particualr window using the [orientationMode property of window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-orientationModes)