# Titanium - Changing orientation between windows

Tags: ios, titanium, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I'm developing an application for ipad and iphone using Titanium. You can navigate between different views. 1st view (the main view where you can go to another views) will be only on portrait mode, the rest of views can be in any orientation.

For this, I use different windows:

```
var winPortrait = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT],
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true,
    backgroundColor : "#00669c",

});

var appWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true,
    backgroundColor : "#00669c",
    backgroundImage : "Default-Portrait.png",
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
});
```

This works ok. When I open each window, orientation changes works ok.

To explain my problem, I'm going to specify the steps I do to reproduce it.

- I'm viewing a screen on landscape:
  [image]
- I click to go to main view (portrait only) with device in landscape.
- Main view is shown in portrait mode.
- I rotate the device to portrait.
- I go to the view again with device in portrait:

[image]

- If I change device orientation, I receive the orientation change event, app detects is landscape mode and draw elements like landscape, but window or view (I don't know) its drawing like portrait, so it doesn't adjust correctly:

[image]

This doesn't occur on ios 7, but when I've tried with ios 5.1, it happens (I doesn't have a device with ios 6.x to try it)

Do you know how can I solve it or is a SO problem?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

This is a simplification of the code I use:

In app.js:

```
var appWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL,
        fullscreen : false,
        navBarHidden : true,
        backgroundColor : "#00669c",
        backgroundImage : "Default-Portrait.png",
        orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
    });

var winPortrait = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT],
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true,
    backgroundColor : "#00669c",

});

var openView = function(e) {

    currentView = e.win;

    if (winPortraitHomeOpened && e.win != 'Home') {
        appWindow.backgroundImage = '';
        appWindow.addEventListener('open', function() {
            //alert("appwindowopen")
            if (appWindow != null) {
                appWindow.height = Ti.UI.FILL;
                appWindow.width = Ti.UI.FILL;
            }
        });
        appWindow.open();

    }

    // Dependiendo de la vista, abre una ventana u otra
    if (e.win == 'Home') {

        winPortrait.open();

        winPortraitHomeOpened = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            var Home = require('/views/Home2');
            activeView = Home.Constructor(winPortrait);
            addActiveViewCloseWin();
        }, 10);

    } else if (e.win == 'test') {
        var Test = require('/views/test/test');
        activeView = Test.Constructor(appWindow, true);
    } 

    if (currentView != 'Home') {
        addActiveViewCloseWin();
    }

};

var addActiveViewCloseWin = function() {
    var anim_invisible = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
        opacity : 0,
        duration : 300
    });
    var anim_visible = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
        opacity : 1,
        duration : 300
    });

    if (winPortraitHomeOpened && currentView == 'Home') {
        winPortrait.add(activeView);
    } else {
        appWindow.add(activeView);
    }

    if (lastActiveView != null) {
        Trace.info("lastActiveView != null");
        lastActiveView.animate(anim_invisible);

        setTimeout(function() {

            activeView.animate(anim_visible);
            lastActiveView.close();

            lastActiveView = activeView;
        }, 300);
    } else {
        activeView.animate(anim_visible);
        lastActiveView = activeView;
    }   
    activeView.updateOrientation();

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (currentView == 'Home') {            
            appWindow.close();          
        } else {
            if (winPortraitHomeOpened) {
                winPortrait.close();
                winPortraitHomeOpened = false;
            }
        }
    }, 500);
};

Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {

    // Comprobar que ha cambiado de orientación. Se envían varios eventos juntos
    var _currentOrientacion = 0;
    if (utils.isLandscape())
        _currentOrientacion = 1;

    if (_currentOrientacion == orientacion) {
        return;
    }

    orientacion = _currentOrientacion;


    // Se actualiza las dimensiones y la orientación de los elementos
    if (!winPortraitHomeOpened && !winPortraitConfOpened) {
        if (appWindow != null) {
            appWindow.height = Ti.UI.FILL;
            appWindow.width = Ti.UI.FILL;
        }
    }

    if (activeView != null) {
        activeView.updateOrientation();
    }
});
```

The code of Test.js:

```
exports.Constructor = function(parent) {

    var view = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : utils.getScreenHeight(),
        width : utils.getScreenWidth(),
        backgroundColor : 'red'
    });

    var cabeceraView = Cabecera.Constructor(view);
    view.add(cabeceraView);
    cabeceraView.setTitle('Prueba');

var backButton = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : utils.imagesFolder() + "common/returnHome.png",
    //top : view.height / 4,
    left : utils.todp(8),
    height : utils.todp(25),
    width : utils.todp(65)
});

   view.add(backButton);

backButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            openView({
                win : 'Home'
            });
        });


    var updateFechaCabecera = function() {
        fechaView.setFecha('XXXX-XX-XX');
    };
    view.updateFechaCabecera = updateFechaCabecera;

    var fechaView = Fecha.Constructor(view);
    view.add(fechaView);

    updateFechaCabecera();

    // Vista ocupa todo salvo cabecera y fecha
    var mainView = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : utils.getScreenHeight() - utils.getCabeceraHeight() - utils.getFechaHeight(),
        width : '100%',
        top : utils.getCabeceraHeight() + utils.getFechaHeight(),
        backgroundColor : "transparent",
    });
    view.add(mainView);

    // Create a Label.
    var aLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : 'aLabel',
        color : 'pink',
        font : {
            fontSize : 40
        },
        textAlign : 'center'
    });

    // Add to the parent view.
    mainView.add(aLabel);

    var updateOrientation = function() {

        Trace.info("updateOrientation de interconexines height width " + utils.getScreenHeight() + ' ' + utils.getScreenWidth());
        view.height = utils.getScreenHeight();
        view.width = utils.getScreenWidth();

        if (utils.isPortrait()) {
            aLabel.text = "PORTRAIT";
        } else {
            aLabel.text = "LANDSCAPE";
        }

    };
    view.updateOrientation = updateOrientation;


    var cerrar = function() {
        Trace.info('cerrar Template');

        view.visible = false;
        view.hide();

        if (cabeceraView != null) {
            cabeceraView.close();
            view.remove(cabeceraView);
            cabeceraView = null;
        }

        if (fechaView != null) {
            fechaView.close();
            view.remove(fechaView);
            fechaView = null;
        }

        //  Eliminamos los elementos de la vista
        if (view != null) {
            utils.removeChildrens(view);
            parent.remove(view);

        };
        view = null;

    };
    view.close = cerrar;

    return view;

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873547/orientation-portrait-and-portraitupsidedown-only-for-one-window

Comment: I'm able to use different orientations in different windows. My problem is when I change between these windows and I play with device orientation (physically). Thank you

Comment: In the orientation change event, are you removing your view and rebuilding it or allowing it to handle the adjustments automatically?  I'd try removing the whole view in the orientation event and calling the function that builds the view again and adding it to the window.  If you could put up a single file code example that exhibits the problem, I could test it on my system.  Your example is good, I just don't want to have to write a mockup app to test it.  It my be a problem with Titanium or the OS in particular.

Comment: In orientation change event, I adjust the elements. I think if I rebuild the view, it takes a lot of time (doesn't it?) and I have to draw a lot of elements. I've checked that the view receives correct dimensions each time (if I would be in landscape, width are bigger than height). I edited the question with a simplification of the code (it's too big), hope it helps. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove orientationModes in var winPortrait?
Your code should look like this:

```
var winPortrait = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true,
    backgroundColor : "#00669c",

});
```

Comment: But I want to allow only portrait orientation in this window (home window) and in the other window allow any orientations. So, I think I have to put it. Thank you